# Dereference symbolic link in OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, symbolic-link, stat

In OS X, how can I dereference a symbolic link to a canonical file name?  (i.e. one starting with `/`.)

That is, I'm after the equivalent of GNU readlink's `-f` option:

```
kapow:~$ greadlink -f .bash_profile
/Users/mjs/.config/home/.bash_profile
```

OS X's `readlink` instead returns a relative link:

```
kapow:~$ readlink .bash_profile
.config/home/.bash_profile
```

`stat(1)` does have an amazing number of options, but I couldn't figure out the right combination to do what I want.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward solution is to test the return value and prepend `pwd` if you find that the readlink has returned a relative path rather than an absolute path stored in the link. Anything not starting with / is simple to test with a variety of unix tools.

---

I don't know if this was a conscious design decision since OS X prefers file system aliases which track a file's unique id as well as the path or is just an omission / difference carried forth from BSD. What is clear is that there is no option to synthesize the full path of the linked file using the OS X version of readlink.

Here are several ready made solutions to implement `read link -f` on OS X from another site...

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac

If you are a fan of GNU tools, you'll want to get [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and install the coreutils package - you can then alias `greadlink` for `readlink` and carry on with a minimal amount of fuss.